# how define handle object in c++/CLR

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

```
MyPractice ^shan=gcnew MyPractice (L"Shahnawaz Talpur");
```

This executes well but I want to first declare variable ^shan and the assign the value how it could be

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? Declaring variables only when you're capable of initializing them is idiomatic in C++ and C++/CLI. What you want to do is only idiomatic in old C code...

Answer (score 1):

Use `nullptr`  :

```
// Declare and assign null
MyPractice^ shan = nullptr;

// Later when you need :
shan = gcnew MyPractice(L"Shahnawaz Talpur");
```